# Is there an idealist rather than realist interpretation of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

The many-worlds interpretation of QM is a realist explanation as it makes the wave function of the universe real. That is it makes the probabilities of outcomes real outcomes.

One could argue that this view is biased that realist ideas of reality are better by definition. But philosophically speaking idealist ideas of realities have been mooted, for example by Berkely & the Cambridge Platonists, (or Brahman in Indian Philosophy).

Is there is an idealist explanation which explains the probabilities inherent in the wave function as epistemological? That is states of knowledge of observers. Except here by observer I do not mean necessarily some one that is conscious, but simply a system that reacts to the information context around it.

Comment: what do you mean by "real" and "real outcomes"? We know, wavefunction is in-general complex

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible answers depending on what you mean by "idealist rather than realist".

You suggest an idealism conceived as an epistemological view, where states of a system are relative to an observer or another system. There are such interpretations with several names, I wonder why, as they seem to be the same : Relational quantum mechanics ; [quantum information and quantum bayesianism](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~bras2317/).

Personally I fail to see how this is an interpretation at all, as it rather looks like the Copenhagen or "shut up and calculate" interpretation, focused on expressing predictions on what you can see, but refusing to answer whether anything is real : what is the sense to discuss the knowledge relatively to an observer (or an observing system), unless you admit that the observer is himself real in some way ?

So, the other way is to replace physical reality by a reality of minds and ideas. That is the [Mind makes collapse interpretation of quantum mechanics](http://settheory.net/quantum-mind-collapse).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Bohmian mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) in which the wavefunction is considered a physical object, existing whether observed or not. Although, to date, it predicts nothing different than the Copenhagen interpretation. Also [t' Hooft](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F65n-C7MheU) has some ideas about a deterministic universe.

Comment: I'm not sure about your first sentence.  For example:  http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9512031  *" These lead us to our main concern: a more careful consideration of the meaning of the wave function in quantum mechanics, as suggested by a Bohmian perspective. We propose that the reason, on the universal level, that there is no action of configurations upon wave functions, as there seems to be between all other elements of physical reality, **is that the wave function of the universe is not an element of physical reality**."*